# How to auto suggest SIM card or Mobile numbers in a device?

Tags: react-native, autocomplete, autosuggest

[image]

This is the Figma and it seems to be used in most of the applications. Is there any npm modules or config need to be added in the  field.

This is the TextInput code that I have used in the app.

I tried 'autoComplete='tel'', But it didn't seem to work.